# ngrx autogenerated selectors not working when nesting features with createFeaute

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

i'm currently facing an issue with ngrx. I want a state structure like this:

- state

  - substate1

    - feature1
    - feature2
  - substate2

I create feature1 and feature2 using the new createFeature syntax like so:

```
    const initialState = {a: 1, b:2 }
    
    export const feature1 = createFeature({
      name: "feature1",
      reducer: createReducer(initalState, ...)
    });
```

This autogenerates selectors on the featur1 object, so i can access feature1.selectA or feature1.selectB.

The problem comes, when i nest these features further.

```
    const substate1Reducer = combineReducers({
        feature1: featur1.reducer,
        feature2: feature1.reducer,
    }),
```

And assign it in the substate1.module:

```
    StoreModule.forFeature("substate1", substate1Reducer),
```

The problem is, that (in a component, for example):

```
    this.store.select(feature1.selectA)
```

is undefined because the autogenerated selectors do not work when the feature is not directly under the root node.

Is there a way to fix this where i can still use the autogenerated selectors without redefining all selectors manually? If not, how can i write something like:

```
    createSelector(
      selectSubstate1, <-- a feature selector? what would the code look like?
      feature1.selectA <-- reusing the auto generated here?
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

That's currently not supported.
A feature state should be added as a child of the rootstate.
In this example this means:

```
StoreModule.forFeature(feature1),
StoreModule.forFeature(feature2),
```

What's the reason/user-case to combine it with `combineReducers` ?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification that this is not currently supported. The idea is to split a feature state further to make our application clearer. Each ngModule should have a feaute state. There is a module in our application that is a bit more complex that a further division of the state would be nicer. 
If the two parts would hang directly under root, it would be unclear that they belong to the module. Of course it would be possible to add a prefix to the name of the feature state.

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)